# What does the hull shader attribute "patchsize" do?

Tags: hlsl, directx11

What does the hull shader attribute `[patchsize(12)]` do? MSDN fails to mention it. Do I have to use it? Should I use it?

Comment: I don't use it and tessellation works perfect. I will try it out however, because never heard of it.

Comment: Incomplete documentation should be punishable. Really. As for tessellation - yeah, mine seems to work just fine too without it, but I'm curious what it does (or maybe did and is deprecated now?).

Comment: Well, tried it but does not make any difference to me (tried a bunch of values like 12, 0, 100, 1000). I think it might be deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`patchsize` appears to describe the number of control points per patch, and seems to be largely ignored (as unnecessary) by the actual compiler. It's possible that at one point it was used as an optimization hint, but doesn't seem to have much practical use.

All real-world examples I can find eschew the attribute. The fact that it appears to only be referred to in the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Hull_Shader_Stage) suggests that the tech writer who created that documentation was given an old bit of example code.

I'd say it's safe to ignore it.